# cfbundledisplayname not change

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode13

I have an application that I developed with swift. I changed cfbundledisplayname in info plist. I changed the display name in the build setting. I changed the name on the certificate. When you login to facebook, the name of the project appears. I want "NewGame" to appear instead of "Kelimeci" how can i change this?

my xcode project name : Kelimeci.xcodeproj

my xcode target name : Kelimeci

cfbundledisplayname (in info.plist) : NewGame

FacebookDisplayName (in info.plist) : NewGame

[image]

[image]

Comment: In TARGETS > your target, under the Identify header, what is the 'Display Name' set to at the top?

Comment: it says "Kelimeci" there. as target name

Comment: I mean when you click that and look in the General tab, what is the Display Name? If it's still the old name, then change that and see if that works

Comment: there is a new name